# 'int' object is not subscriptable in Otree

Tags: python, syntax-error, otree

i am trying to compare the response that someone give me in a questionarie with a predetermined value, can someone give me a expleneation
I have the next code.

```
class CRT(Page):
form_model = 'player'
form_fields = ['CRT1','CRT2','CRT3','CRT4',]

def CRT1_error_message(self, value):
    print('Escogiste', value)
    if value['CRT1'] != -2:
        return 'Recuerda que se esta preguntando sobre la respuesta de la mayoría de sujetos, por favor revisa el cuadro que se presenta arriba'
```

But I get the next error .

'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `value` is an integer, not a dictionary

Comment: What should I do to fix this ?

Comment: Changing `if value['CRT1'] != -2:` to `if value != -2:` would make the code run but I can't tell you if it would produce the correct results (I don't know what the code is supposed to do)